# Android applying border around SurfaceView

Tags: android

I have one `SurfaceView` for which I want to display a border of `20dp` size which will flow around the `SurfaceView`. I need 'SurfaceView' in `16:9` aspect ratio, so i kept the size of the `SurfaceView` to `161x286` which is in `16:9` ratio.

To display border around the surface view i have following implementation in XML.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_surface_view_holder"
    android:layout_height="161dp"
    android:layout_width="286dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    >
    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/video_surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above code displays the border around the `SurfaceView` properly but it breaks the 16:9 aspect ration of the video as i have given padding of `20dp` for displaying border.

If i adjust aspect ration according to the border size then border is not evenly set, on top/bottom it is different and on left/right it is different.

So How can i display the border around SurfaceView by keeping it's aspect ration maintained to size 161x286.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want a background, border, then the surface? how about leaving margins outside the RelativeLayout, to the left and right of it?

Comment: Yes i need border for Surface, and for that i have added surface view in a Relative layout and that relative layout has background image set to it and a padding which acts as border to surface view. that is the trick i used but it is breaking the aspect ration of my video.

Comment: Keep your relative layout height and width to (161+20) , (286+20) respectively. Try this I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @Android_Crazy: 161+20 and 286+20 is not in 16:9 aspect ratio.

Comment: @PP since you are giving padding to relativelayout to 20dp
hence surfaceview is getting 161-20 height and 286-20 width which breaks 16:9 ratio.If you increase height and width by 20 then the height and width the surfaceview will get is 161 and 286 which is 16:9 ratio.this was the logic behind it.If you are convienced with the logic then give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the way and it was pretty simple. I set the size of SurfaceView to 161X286 and then i set the RelativeLayout to wrap contains for width and height and then i set padding to the RelativeLayout which displays the border around the SurfaceView.

So my SurfaceView maintains the aspect Ration of 16:9 and it has RelativeLayout as it's background border.

Thanks everyone for your comments.